# Does delta lake support update with join?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

Is it possible to do update on a delta lake table with join? In mysql (and other databases) you could something like

```
update table x 
join table y on y.a=x.a 
set x.b=y.b
where x.c='something'
```

Do we have something similar in delta? I know they support in and exists clause. Their documentation does not seem to mention anything about update join

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with MERGE INTO command. Something like:

```
    merge into x using y
    on (x.a=y.a and x.c='something')
    when matched then
    update set x.b=y.b;
```

Comment: thanks Dipesh. any idea how we can use join optimizations like skew (....) ?

Comment: @Ridwan Can you please describe your use-case? To start with, You can have a look at performance improvements here: https://kb.databricks.com/delta/delta-merge-into.html#how-to-improve-performance-of-delta-merge-into-queries-using-partition-pruning